# guarantee MongoDB update operation is successful

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-collections

Maybe a dumb question, how to guarantee your update operation is successful?
This is how I did it, but the returned "result" is "false".

```
import { Mongo } from "meteor/mongo";
const Employees = new  Mongo.Collection("Employees");

const result = Employees.update({_id: employeeId}, {$push: {tasks: taskId}});
console.log(result); // "false"
```

Thanks

Derek

Comment: Did you do it on the client or on the server? On the server, you get the number of affected documents. On the client you don't get the result synchronously.

Comment: @MasterAM So on the server side, it is working synchronously while on client side, it is working asynchronously?

Comment: On the server, it uses fibers to allow you to write seemingly synchronous code (it wraps the async native Mongo functions) and on the client it simulates the action in MiniMongo and calls an auto-generated method on the server. Those requests are asynchronous and the client has no way of really knowing the result until the method returns a response.

Answer (score 1):

All depends what you class as successful? If you take a look at [WriteConcern](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/write-concern/) you can get results for acknowledgments, write to journal or writes to a number of nodes with the cluster. This will all depend on your application and how it can deal with failures.

As for getting the number of effected rows you can use the call back on the update method (see the [API documentation](https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection-update))

> **callback Function**
>
> Optional. If present, called with an error object as the first argument and, if no error, the number of affected documents as the second.